# null pointer exception while trying to load file using the File class

Tags: java, file, nullpointerexception

I have 2 files Details.java and TestDetails.java and a data file called Details.dat

**Details.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Details {
    private String path;
    File myFile = new File(path);

    public void setMyFile(String path) {
        this.path = path;

    }

    public void load() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(myFile);

        int numberOfMembers = input.nextInt();

        String[] members = new String[numberOfMembers];

        for (String s : members) {

            String name = input.next();

            String age = input.next();

            String qualification = input.next();

            System.out.println("The name of the family member is " + name + " the age of the family member is" + age
                    + " the qualification of the " + "family member is" + qualification);

        }
    }
}
```

**TestDetails.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestDetails {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Details myDetails = new Details();

        myDetails.setMyFile(args[0]);

        try {
            myDetails.load();
        } catch (IOException i) {

            System.out.println(i.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Details.dat**

```
4

a 26 bsc

b 22 bcom

c 50 ba

d 60 bsc
```

Whenever i try to run the TestDetails.java file i get a NullPointerException and the stack trace points the stack trace towards the File object.

So what is the problem here? Why am i getting a NullPointerException?

p.s in the setFile() method argumnet, i pass in Details.dat in the args[0] position on the command prompt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initialize the File first and after that set the file path.
Try to use a constructor in the Details class:

```
public Details(String path)
        this.path = path;
        myFile = new File(path);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this:

```
public class Details{
    private String path;
    File myFile = new File(path);
    ...
```

The `File myFile = new File(path)` line will be executed when the object is constructed. This means that `path` is null at the time this line is executed.

You should change your code so that the `File` object is instantiated only when you need it.

Comment: Yep, move `myFile = new File(path);` to `setMyFile`.  (Leave the declaration `File myFile;` at the class level, though.)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Details{
   private  String path;
   File myFile =new File(path);
   ...
```

How is `myFile` ever going have its path set to anything other than `""`?

Comment: It's going to have its path set to `null`, not `""`.

Comment: True.  I "blanked" out there for a second.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a File object with path name without initializing path. Because

```
File myFile = new File(path);
```

line will be executed before setting path and at that time it is null. So first set value of path and then make object of File.